# HTML/CSS/JScript app vs Objective-c or Java app

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I am trying to decide which of these types of apps would be better in the long run. I know that developing an app in HTML/CSS can be used on all the different OS, but I feel like they aren't as reliable as a true Objective-C or Java app would be.

I am hoping that the app I am making will get lots of user activity, so I want something that can withstand all of the pressure.

Can you all throw in some ideas?

Comment: I think it also depends on what type of an app you are going to build..? Also, have you looked at PhoneGap?

Comment: This [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192866/any-advantage-of-programming-natively-for-mobile-development/8193354#8193354) that I wrote for another question may be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very situation specific.

> I know that developing an app in HTML/CSS can be used on all the
>   different OS

That is true.  Mobile devices can simply view your application in a web browser.  It is also easier publish newer versions of your application, since you only have to do it once.

> but I feel like they aren't as reliable as a true Objective-C or Java
>   app would be.

Define reliable?  Your web app will obviously require the internet to view, but I personally think that the reliability is mostly do to how well the application is written, regardless of language.

> Can you all throw in some ideas

The main advantage of creating a native application (written in java or obj-c) is being able to access the phones hardware and capabilities.  If your application is not required to get data or strongly interact with the phone, a web app will be sufficient.  It is going to heavily depend on what your requirements are.   If you are looking to use on multiple platforms, it will be easier to write a web app.

Comment: Well I am going to be building a social networking site. It will be photo-oriented with a Maps API and other cool items integrated. I personally think Java & Obj-c would be a better approach.

Comment: Notice the first sentence in my answer... Yes. If you want an application like that, you will want the phone hardware at your disposal. If you are going that large scale, it would be to your advantage to have both.  You could do it simply by making a mobile css sheet for your current website.

Answer (score 1):

When I build anything bigger than quiz game or simple tweeter app I use Java, simply because prototyping in Java is easier as it is a much richer language than JavaScript.

But it also depends on what type of app You are developing, and which technologies You are planning to use.